# with path.open('r', encoding="utf-8") as file: AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'open'

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree

I am not really sure how to access the file names and do the necessary changes as written in the script? I am trying to access some files which are inside the folders.
I also want to use these files as shown in line

`item = etree.Element('language', attrib={"lang": path.parent.name, "status": "Reviewed"})`

````
import pathlib
import functools
import operator
import lxml.etree as etree
from lxml.builder import ElementMaker

ATTRIB = {"xsi": "test.xsd", "xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"}



def is_element(node):
    return hasattr(node, 'attrib') and 'name' in node.attrib


def create_plural(item):
    pass



def main():
    cwd = pathlib.Path.cwd()
    directories = list(filter(lambda path: path.is_dir(), cwd.iterdir()))
    langs = [path.name for path in directories]
    files = map(operator.methodcaller('glob', '*.xml'), directories)
    #trees = dict.fromkeys(unique_names, dict())


    for path in files:
        with path.open('r', encoding="utf-8") as file:
            tree = etree.parse(file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        name = xml_path.with_suffix('').with_suffix('').name
        out_tree = trees[name]



        for child in filter(is_element, root):
            id = child.attrib['name']
            text = child.text
            if id not in out_tree:
                out_tree[id] = list()
            item = etree.Element('language', attrib={"lang": path.parent.name, "status": "Reviewed"})
            if child.tag == "plurals":
                item.text = create_plural(child)
            else:
                item.text = etree.CDATA(text)
            out_tree[id].append(item)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()



    #name = '{}.strings.xml'.format(xml_file.with_suffix('').name)  # name of the file
        #out_p = out_path / lang / name  # path of the output file where it should be located
        #out_p.parent.resolve().mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)  # make directory
        #text = etree.tostring(root, xml_declaration=True, pretty_print=True, encoding="utf-8")
        #with out_p.open('wb') as file:
        #    file.write(text) ```
````

Comment: what are you getting in files ?

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya I am getting <map object at 0x7fd4010ae6d8>

Comment: files should be of file type so that you can open it, map objects can't be opened as files

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya any ideas how to solve it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
with path.open('r', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    tree = etree.parse(file)
```

You can pass a filename (string) directly to parse:

```
tree = etree.parse(path)
```

`path` in your example is a string so it doesn't have an `open` function.

Maybe you meant:

```
with open(path, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    tree = etree.parse(file)
```

If you trying to find xml file names in the current directory:

```
[f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.endswith('.xml')]
```

Comment: I tried it like this , `def main():


   ` for path in files:`
        `tree = etree.parse(path)`
        `root = tree.getroot()`
        `name = xml_path.with_suffix('').with_suffix('').name`
        `out_tree = trees[name]`
        `for child in filter(is_element, root):`
        `    id = child.attrib['name']`
        `    text = child.text``
It is not giving any errors , but when i try print tree , or name , or even path it is not giving anything !
Any advice please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this:

> ```
> files = map(operator.methodcaller('glob', '*.xml'), directories)
> ```

`glob` returns a generator of paths, so `file` is not a sequence of paths but a sequence of sequences of path.

You need to either `itertools.chain.from_iterable` the entire thing into a single sequence, or use a nested loop. Or use a comprenension to staight unwrap the entire thing. `map` makes a lot of sense when you already have a function doing what you need but that's not the case here so comprehensions tend to be prefereable:

```py
files = (
    f
    for d in directories
    for f in d.glob('*.xml')
)
```

Comment: I tried changing it as you are writing, but it didnt work.
It is not giving any errors , but when i try print tree , or name , or even path it is not giving anything ! Any advice please? Thanks

Comment: Hard to know without more information. Note that `files` here is a *generator* so it can only be iterated once. If you want to use it multiple times (e.g. print it then do things with it), replace the parenthesis at the top and bottom lines by brackets (`[` and `]`).